# decode all values to zero if Sequence <= 3 keeping certain informations

Tags: r, select, data.table, sequence

I ask a similar question before, but I need some further output and decided to post a new question.

I have a data.table object like this:

```
library(data.table)
cells <- c(100, 1,1980,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,
       150, 1,1980,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,
       99 , 1,1980,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
       899, 1,1980,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,
       789, 1,1982,1,1,1,0,1,1,1 )
colname <- c("number","sex", "birthy", "2004","2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009","2010")
rowname <- c("1","2","3","4","5")
y <- matrix(cells, nrow=5, ncol=10, byrow=TRUE, dimnames =   list(rowname,colname))
y <- data.table(y, keep.rownames = TRUE)
```

The value 1 in the column 2004 means that this person is continuous insured during the year 2004. Person being insured for 3 preceding years can be part of the study. I need a subset of this data.table containing all observation where the following condition is true: 2004+2005+2006 = 3 or 2005+2006+2007 = or 2006+2007+...

```
#using melt and rle function to restrucure the data
tmp <- melt(y, id = "rn", measure.vars = patterns("^20"),
        variable.factor = FALSE, variable.name = "year")[, rle(value), by = rn]

#subset data based on condition, keeping only the first relevant sequence
tmp2 <- tmp[(values == 1 & lengths >= 3), .(rn,lengths)][, .SD[1,], by=rn]
##selecting only rows with value=1 and min 3 in a row
##keeping only the variable rn
tmp3 <- tmp[values == 1, which(max(lengths) >= 3), by = rn]$rn

##using the row-number to select obersvations from data.table
##merging length of sequence
dt <- merge(y[as.integer(tmp3)],tmp2, by="rn")
```

Is there a way to turn all 1 to 0 if they are not part of a sequence? For example rn==4 variable "2005" needs to be a zero.

I also need a new variable "begy" containing the year of the beginning of the sequence. For example `rn==5` and `begy==2004`. Any Suggestion will be appreciated...

Comment: Please, can you specify what the espected result is if there are multiple periods. E.g., `rn == 5` has one period starting in 2004 and a second starting in 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option using rolling window:

```
#convert into long format and convert data types
DT <- melt(y, id="rn", measure.vars=patterns("^20"),
    variable.factor=FALSE, variable.name="YEAR", 
    value.factor=FALSE, value.name="VALUE")
cols <- c("YEAR", "VALUE")
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.integer), .SDcols=cols]
setorder(DT, rn, YEAR)

#for each row, sum the value that is between current year and 2 years from now
winsize <- 3L
DT[, roll3y := vapply(YEAR,
        function(k) sum(VALUE[between(YEAR, k, k + winsize - 1L)]),
        integer(1L)), 
    by=.(rn)]

#> Is there a way to turn all 1 to 0 if they are not part of a sequence?
#reset all values to 0 and set only those in sequence to 1
DT[, VALUE := 0L][
    c(outer(DT[roll3y==winsize, which=TRUE], 0L:2L, `+`)), VALUE := 1L]

#> I also need a new variable "begy" containing the year of the beginning of the sequence.
#identify the year that a sequence of 3 ones appears
longDT <- rbindlist(list(DT,
        DT[roll3y==winsize, .(YEAR="begy", VALUE=min(YEAR)), by=.(rn,number,sex,birthy)]),
    use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)

#get desired output
dcast(longDT, rn + number + sex + birthy ~ YEAR, value.var="VALUE")
```

output:

```
   rn number sex birthy 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 begy
1:  1    100   1   1980    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   NA
2:  2    150   1   1980    1    1    1    0    0    0    0 2004
3:  3     99   1   1980    1    1    1    1    0    0    0 2004
4:  4    899   1   1980    0    0    0    1    1    1    1 2007
5:  5    789   1   1982    1    1    1    0    1    1    1 2004
```

Answer (score 3):

**New solution:**

```
# define a custom function in order to only keep the sequences
# with 3 (or more) consecutive years
rle3 <- function(x) {
  r <- rle(x)
  r$values[r$lengths < 3 & r$values == 1] <- 0
  inverse.rle(r)
}

# replace all '1'-s that do not belong to a sequence of at least 3 to '0'
# create 'begy'-variable
melt(y, id = 1:4, measure.vars = patterns("^20"),
     variable.factor = FALSE, variable.name = "year"
     )[, value := rle3(value), by = rn
       ][, begy := year[value == 1][1], rn
         ][, dcast(.SD[!is.na(begy)], ... ~ year, value.var = "value")]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    rn number sex birthy begy 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
> 1:  2    150   1   1980 2004    1    1    1    0    0    0    0
> 2:  3     99   1   1980 2004    1    1    1    1    0    0    0
> 3:  4    899   1   1980 2007    0    0    0    1    1    1    1
> 4:  5    789   1   1982 2004    1    1    1    0    1    1    1
> ```

---

**Old solution:**

```
# define a custom function in order to only keep the sequences
# with 3 (or more) consecutive years
rle3 <- function(x) {
  r <- rle(x)
  r$values[r$lengths < 3 & r$values == 1] <- 0
  inverse.rle(r)
}

# create a reference 'data.table' with only the row to keep
# and the start year of the (first) sequence (row 5 has 2 sequences of 3)
x <- melt(y, id = "rn", measure.vars = patterns("^20"),
          variable.factor = FALSE, variable.name = "year"
          )[, value := rle3(value), by = rn
            ][value == 1, .SD[1], rn]

# join 'x' with 'y' to add 'begy' and filter out the row with no sequences of 3
y[x, on = "rn", begy := year][!is.na(begy)]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    rn number sex birthy 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 begy
> 1:  2    150   1   1980    1    1    1    0    0    0    1 2004
> 2:  3     99   1   1980    1    1    1    1    0    0    0 2004
> 3:  4    899   1   1980    0    1    0    1    1    1    1 2007
> 4:  5    789   1   1982    1    1    1    0    1    1    1 2004
> ```

Comment: Thanks Jaab, using your example I still got all five observation with begy=2010 for the first observation. But I combined some of the old syntax with your suggestion and it seems to work.

Comment: @AlinaLudewig Hmm, strange .... Could you include the code in your question where the output still included the first row?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, my global environment was filled up with old stuff. Your example works fine!

Comment: @Jaap, Nice solution. However, it only appends `begy` but does not turn isolated `1`s into `0`s as requested. The value for 2005 in row 4 is still `1`.

Comment: @AlinaLudewig Updated my answer to fully reflect the requirements in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has requested

1. to turn all `1`s into `0`s if they are not part of a sequence of 3 or more consecutive years,
2. to add a new column which contains the year in which "the" sequence begins.

Note that the 2nd requirement is ambiguous as there might be more than one sequence of 3 or more consecutive years, e.g., in row 5. Here, we take the beginning year of the first (oldest) sequence.

The solution below

- reshapes from wide to long format,
- computes the lengths of streaks of consecutive years,
- turns `1`s into `0`s if they are not part of a sequence of 3  or more consecutive years,
- gets the beginning year of the first sequence,
- removes rows without consecutive sequence (no `begy` found), and
- reshapes back to wide format, finally.

No rolling window or custom function is required.

```
library(data.table)
melt(y, , patterns("^\\d"))[
  order(rn), N := .N, by = .(rleid(value), rn)][
    value == 1 & N < 3, value := 0][
      , begy := first(variable[value == 1]), by = rn][
        , dcast(.SD[!is.na(begy), -"N"], ... ~ variable)]
```

> ```
>    rn number sex birthy begy 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
> 1:  2    150   1   1980 2004    1    1    1    0    0    0    0
> 2:  3     99   1   1980 2004    1    1    1    1    0    0    0
> 3:  4    899   1   1980 2007    0    0    0    1    1    1    1
> 4:  5    789   1   1982 2004    1    1    1    0    1    1    1
> ```